# How to remove unique constraint using South?

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

I'm trying to delete a `unique` constraint defined in two model fields (using South 0.8.2).

I need to go from:

```
billing_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Billing id"), unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
tax_code = models.CharField(_("Tax code"), max_length=10, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

To:

```
billing_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Billing id"), blank=True, null=True)
tax_code = models.CharField(_("Tax code"), max_length=10, blank=True, default='')
```

However, when I run the migration I get the following error:

```
Warning: Data truncated for column 'tax_code' at row 1
```

If I run it again, then I get:

```
ValueError: Cannot find a UNIQUE constraint on table startups_startup, columns ['billing_id']
```

Reached this point, I have to manually recreate the unique index.

There are existing records on the table and I'm using MySQL.

Is there an "easy way" to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this I did the following:

1. Remove the unique constraint, run `schemamigration` and migrate it.
2. Remove the null=True from `tax_code`, run `schemamigration` and migrate it again.

Step 2) has shown a `Truncated data` warning, but it ran fine. Re-migrating it doesn't show any errors, so everything seems fine!

Hope this helps somebody else too!